# Sprite Kit Physics Body Complex Shape - Spritekit

Tags: sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I have this situation: http://mokainteractive.com/example.png

I'd like to move the white ball inside the red track and detect wherever the balls touch the limit of the red track.

Which is the best solution? I have to create multiple transparent shape along the borders? Do you have other ideas?
thanks so much

Comment: You can make use of `+bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath:`. It will be hard work, but could be worth it.

Answer (score 4):

In **iOS8** you can create a single physics body for that kind of shape.

Make a texture of your shape with p.e. Adobe Illustrator and use this method:

```
init(texture texture: SKTexture!,alphaThreshold alphaThreshold: CFloat,size size: CGSize) -> SKPhysicsBody
```

- The `SKTexture` is your shaped image. The body is defined by the colored pixels.
- The alphaThresHold: The minimum alpha value for texels that should be part of the new physics body.
- The Size is clear I think.

The texture is analyzed and all invisible pixels around the egg are ignored and only the color pixels are interpreted as the body of the SKPhysicsNode. You should use too many of these because they are very expensive to calculate for the Physics Engine.

Variations of this method are found in the [SpriteKit Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithTexture%3aalphaThreshold%3asize%3a).

---

To your problem. Make an inverse texture of your area which should be transparent and pass it as texture to the physics body. It will be analyzed and a body around the free zone is created.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot create a single physics body for that kind of shape.

Using `bodyWithPolygonFromPath:` will only allow you to create a convex polygonal path which obviously does not work for your shape.

I think you have 3 options here:

1. Use a number of `bodyWithPolygonFromPath:` bodies (probably the hardest to do and time consuming).
2. Use a number of various size `bodyWithRectangleOfSize:` bodies (not so hard but time consuming).
3. Use only straight lines in your image and use `bodyWithRectangleOfSize:` (the easiest and fastest). If you choose this option remember you are still free to rotate your straight lines to various angles.